# netbeans red badge issues with non-bundled maven

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am seeing a problem and need a bit of assistance please.

My team has just upgraded to version 7.3 (mixed os, linux/windows) and we are all seeing strange behaviour in netbeans.

We are using a non-bundled version of maven (2.2.1) and have set this in the java/maven options page.

Builds work fine from netbeans (clean and build shows no errors) and also from the maven command line.

Even though the build works, the projects show red badges, due to missing 3rd party dependencies.

Switching to the bundled maven within Netbeans(7.3) causes Netbeans to successfully download the jars, but using the non bundled maven does not download them.

For example:

1. I have a clean project space (no red badges)
2. Go to my /.m2 repository and remove the folder:
   /.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans
3. Build a project that has import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
4. jars deleted in step 2 get re-downloaded:

   Copying 5 resources

   Downloading: (our nexus URL)/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom

   2K downloaded (spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom)

   Downloading: (our nexus URL)/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.pom

   2K downloaded (spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.pom)

   Downloading: (our nexus URL)/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.pom

   2K downloaded (spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.pom)

   Downloading: (our nexus URL)/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar

   583K downloaded (spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar)
5. Build succeeds and project jar gets created.
6. Source now has import from step 3 underlined in red, with the error hint:
   package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation dos not exist
7. project window now has lots of red badge errors.
8. switch maven to the bundled version and do a clean build, and the red badges go away.

Now. If I switch to the bundled maven, and repeat the previous steps, I do not get any red badge errors.

Is there some additional configuration that I need to do to get the non bundled version of maven working, or does netbeans just not work without the bundled version?

Note:  I created a post in the netbeans forums, but am cross posting here because this site seems to get more traffic.  If we get an answer, I will update both posts.

```
http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=147520#147520
```

Comment: Does anything happen if you right click on the project and reload it?  In between steps 7 and 8.  Although, I believe that the bundled version of Maven is version 3.  There are probably metadata changes within the local repository between version 2 and 3 of Maven.  I know I use an external installation of Maven (Maven 3) and I don't have these errors.  Maybe the plugin is assuming a specific version?

Comment: doing reload project does not resolve the red badge issues.  On linux, cleaning the cache and restarting the ide fixes it, and on windows even doing that does not fix it.

Comment: a note on the netbeans user group forum indicates that:  this seems a problem (already fixed in DEV builds, and probably will be fixed in 7.3.1 when available).  Search bugzilla for "badge" and you will find it. (from Edson).  I will update this when I see if it works.